# Dynamically create array of buttons

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to dynamically create a list of buttons from an array. The first part of each element pair contains the button value and the second part contains the button name.

This is the code I have so far which creates a list of buttons from the array but the names are not linked properly (the names appear next to the buttons, not in them)

How do I correctly format this to do what I need?

```
<head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type=text/javascript>
        setInterval(function() {
            $.getJSON('/_load_node', {
            }, function(data) {
              if(data.test_result == 1) {
                $("div.value").html(data.test_result);
                var newHTML = [];
                for (var i = 0; i < data.next_steps.length; i++) {
                    newHTML.push('<p><button type="submit" name="action" value = ' + data.next_steps[i][0] + ' />' + data.next_steps[i][1] + '</button>');
                }
                $("div.button").html(newHTML.join(""));
              }
            return false;
          });
        }, 1000);
    </script>

</head>
<body>
<div class="value"></div>
<div class="button"></div>
</body>
```

Inspecting the page, it looks like the buttons are being returned as `<p><button type="submit" name="action" value = value/> </button> name` which makes sense for them to be printed to the side. Is there a way to get this to return correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `button` tag was already closed in the opening.

```
newHTML.push(
    '<p><button type="submit" name="action" value = '
    + data.next_steps[i][0]
    + ' />' // was closing this
    + data.next_steps[i][1]
    + '</button>');
```

Fix it up to

```
newHTML.push(
  '<p><button type="submit" name="action" value = ' 
  + data.next_steps[i][0] 
  + '>' 
  + data.next_steps[i][1]
  + '</button>');
```

Answer (score 0):

Also use quotes because this is a string :

```
newHTML.push('<p><button type="submit" name="action" value="' + data.next_steps[i][0] + '">' + data.next_steps[i][1] + '</button>');
```